# Copy Database Entities into Another Layer in Software Architecture?

Tags: c#, architecture, .net

We are using Entity Framework with SqlServer Database. Business program needs to create many columns which are not in the Database, due to storage, high querying cost etc. Currently, the team is Copying the whole DB Entity Layer (from scaffolding), and Creating whole another layer adding computed members in new entities. Currently taking EF layer and applying AutoMapper to new layer. For some reason, not sure if this is optimal, however architect wants it this way.

Is it general practice in Software industry to copy the Database layer into another Copy layer with Computed Members? I'm aware of DDD Domain Driven Design, however we are not creating Aggregate Roots, Value Objects, Clusters, etc.

What is an alternate solution if this is not good practice?

*I started software programming two years ago from college, curious if this is good industry practice, or alternative exists. Searched all over google and stack, and did not cite this strategy.

So basically

SQL Database ---> EF Layer  ---> Another Copy Layer (with EF and computer members in the class) ---> Application Service --->  Dto ---> Controller APIs

I agree with every layer, excepted this EF copy layer with computed members. Couldn't we just utilize partial classes?

Example: New class layer would contain all existing members, plus these  added in a class, etc.

```
FullName => FirstName + LastName

AccountValue => Quantity * StockPrice
```

**Update:**

Would like to hear from people who think differently also, appreciate answers below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it general practice in Software industry to copy the Database layer into another Copy layer with Computed Members?
>
> Example: New class layer would contain all existing members, plus these added in a class, etc.
>
> `FullName => FirstName + LastName`
> `AccountValue => Quantity * StockPrice`

What you're seeing used here is the **distinction between the entity** (= the database record) **and the domain object** (= the "fuller" data object). This is not unique to DDD. DDD does emphasize it more strongly than other approaches, but it's a perfectly viable approach even in non-DDD scenarios.

Where would you put your computed values? You shouldn't store them in the database (unnecessary data size bloat), and you want these computed values to be readily accessible by all consumers of your domain. Logically, the domain must then wrap this around the db record, which is the "copy layer" you're referring to.

---

Referring to it as a "copy layer" suggests to me that you don't see the purpose of abstraction layers.

This layer is not a copy, it is a separate layer with its own functional purpose (one of which is to abstract away the database entities from the domain). It just happens to partially resemble the database entities because it exposes similar data (among other things).

That is not to say I don't see where your interpretation comes from. It often feels unnecessary to write something that effectively duplicates another layer. While this additional abstraction may not be necessary today (if it completely resembles the database layer), it's much easier to implement from the beginning than it is to have to retroactively add it in at a later stage when it *does* become necessary.

In that sense, it is necessary to implement this abstraction layer today, in order to avoid a more cumbersome task tomorrow.

Comment: why not just utilize partial classes?

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1: Partial classes make no difference here. They are essentially the same as having one class which contains the same content that you would've spread across those partial classes. There is no meaningful difference with (nor reason to use) partial classes in your scenario.

Comment: well I thought about using partial classes, just to eliminiate the need for another layer with computed columns, ok well thanks

Comment: by the way, could I just create a console program which will copy all the files into another project for this new layer everytime we rescaffold? I was considering doing this, and then writing partial classes on top of this new layer

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1: Can it be done? Sure. But it misses the point that one day this copy might no longer be an exact copy, at which point your copy process is unusable. If that day never comes, then the abstraction was somewhat unnecessary (but that still doesn't mean you should've gambled on this by not making the abstraction - caution has value even if things don't go wrong).

Comment: well, not sure how it would differ, just made the point that we are copying entities framework classes into this new layer, not arguing just saying how could  they differ?

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1: Them differing (whether now or potentially in the future) is exactly the purpose of the abstraction layer. You can't always account today for things that happen tomorrow. I can't tell you how/why they will differ in the future - your product owners might not even know yet. What I'm saying is that by introducing the abstraction layer, your codebase is well prepared to minimize the impact of implementing a change (in the future) which causes them to differ.

Comment: yeah, not sure, I brought this question up to architect, no one seems to answer this question anyway, thank you though

Comment: thank you, really appreciate the answer, can you maybe help answer this question here, with this new copy abstraction layer discussed? and best way of implementing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607240/writing-computed-members-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 The keyword you should be focusing on is "DTO", more specifically why you need to use one. [Example article](https://guntherpopp.blogspot.com/2010/09/to-dto-or-not-to-dto.html). This is a common discussion topic but I suspect you may have missed out as "copying" is not a term related to it.

Comment: well, I agree with the DTO layer, we have that, but we have another layer, I posted another question, I agree with what you said, but seems like we are duplicating efforts, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403478/application-service-layer-referring-to-two-layers-and-database-entity-copy-laye

Comment: either way, I sent points, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is common practice.

It seems weird with EF because EF makes objects for you. If you were just using SqlClient with DataReaders and the like directly you wouldnt think twice.

**The problem is the EF objects are often tightly coupled to EF via attributes.** This means wherever you use the Object you have to reference EF. Which you don't really want to do when you are not using it.

In theory you could do code first EF objects and use the Business Layer objects directly, but in practice its sometimes easier just to map the EF objects to a Business Layer via the repository pattern

Comment: why not just utilize partial classes? thanks

Comment: Even when using code first on domain objects (with no attributes etc), it's still better to separate the db entity from the domain object. A domain object can exist of more than just its db entity (e.g. if certain information is retrieved from another data source). Entities and domain objects do not have the same functional purpose and conflating them will lead to an unpleasant exercise in having to separate them at a later stage.

Comment: partial classes are just single classes in two files. They dont solve anything

Comment: @Flater there is no such thing as a "DB Entity"

Comment: by the way, could I just create a console program which will copy all the files into another project for another? I was considering doing this, and then writing partial classes on top of this new layer

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 "The problem is the EF objects are often tightly coupled to EF via attributes"

Comment: yeah, was considering finding a way to remove the unnecessary attributes, I am mean  I am looking at the entity and new business layer, shouldnt be too hard

Comment: @Ewan: I refer to it as a _db_ entity to clearly distinguish it from the _domain_ object. When people conflate the two, they often refer to it as just "the entity", which is exactly where I wanted to make a clear separation.

Comment: @Flater that is where you are going wrong

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 obvs there are a few ways you could save typing, but tbh I find that this kind of automatic generation isnt a great idea in the long run. By the time your write it, you could have manually typed up the classes

Comment: well we do scaffolding every sprint with new classes, it got it up and running in couple hours

Comment: thank you, really appreciate the answer, can you maybe help answer this question here, with this new copy abstraction layer discussed? and best way of implementing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607240/writing-computed-members-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: by the way, what is the name of this key architectural term of copying the entity later? is there an architectural term, I never read any papers on the strategy, only see it at workplace, would like to read more about it

Comment: gave points, thumbs up answer, , wish I could accept both answers, however both are good, thanks!  I have another question here, if you don't mind https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403478/application-service-layer-referring-to-two-layers-and-database-entity-copy-laye

Comment: feel free to to thumbs up question, I can start a bounty and split points if needed